# Didn't play video with AVPLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I use AVPlayer for playing video from URL. Below code that I use:

```
@implementation VideoPlayerController  {
    IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.videoUrl];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [self startPlaybackForItemWithURL:videoURL];

}

-(void)startPlaybackForItemWithURL:(NSURL*)url {

    // First create an AVPlayer
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    self.player = player;
    // Begin playback
    [player play];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];
    [self.player pause];

}

@end
```

So on iOS 12 device video loading very long time, but after this is playing... But on some devices (on iOS 11.4, iPhone 7 32 Gb) there are some error:

```
Task <7813A625-BBCF-4486-BC48-D6B066129F41>.<2> finished with error - code: -999
Task <37ED66A3-0404-414D-969E-CB5E118BDE4B>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
TIC Read Status [40:0x0]: 1:57
Task <37ED66A3-0404-414D-969E-CB5E118BDE4B>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: 12 [1:12])
```

The example of video from media server that I must use to playing videos is [here](https://krsk2019.ru/video/a/q5ctCuhICm)

I need help mb with code, or mb the video is bad for playing.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the `status` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388096-status?language=objc), you might get a more explicit error. Also, did you allow the App Transport Security ? Is you video really compatible with `AVPlayer` (you can't play all video format)?

Comment: @Larme ty for your comment. Video has mp4 format, its playing with big delay, but playing on iOS 12 (iPhone 7 128 gb). But on simulator - iPhone X iOS 11.4 has the same issue. I already allow App Transport Security and `status` show the same errors with one more - -1001 code error

Comment: And if you open that link into Safari?

Comment: @Larme on device where I can't play video - in Safari doesn't play (crossed play logo)

Comment: I am not familiar with the error but I would check the media - loading the video in a browser has following range request `0-27770619/27770620` which means the client had to wait for download of the whole movie which is not optimal for streaming. I would check if the movie(s) are exported with `moov` atom shifted to the beginning of the mp4 file.

Comment: @PeterPajchl thanks for your comment! So, if I Understand right - Video doesnt start playback until it's full download... But on iOS 12 it's starts play after little slice is download... Can you told me more please

Comment: @PeterPajchl also i discover that this issue only with video with length nearly 1 min and higher...

Comment: To be more clear - please check details of what the moov atom provides https://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html. The atom can appear in at arbitrary place (often at the end) but without the information the client cannot start. Most packagers offer flag to move the atom to the beginning of the file to avoid this. I ca't confirm if this is causing the error though.

Comment: @PeterPajchl Thank you for your answer. I will check this!